# Make content of a dynamically created cell bold when clicked using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

HTML:

```
<table id="table">"
</table>
<input type="text" id="text1">
<input type="text" id="text2">
<input type="text" id="text3">
<button onclick="addRow()">Add Row</button>
```

Add Row Function:

```
function appendRow() {
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    {
      var row = table.insertRow(-1);
      var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
      cell1.innerHTML = "<p onclick=\"bold()\">words</p>;

    }
}
```

Currently empty bold function

```
function bold() {

}
```

When the text in a cell is clicked I want to make it bold, however I'm not quite sure how I would do this due to the lack of id values from having dynamically created the content of the cells.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
//add parameter into onclick trigger function
cell1.innerHTML = "<p onclick=\"bold(this)\">words</p>";

function bold(obj){
    //using the innerHTML to change content
    obj.innerHTML = '<b>' + obj.innerHTML + '</b>';
    // OR using CSS
    obj.style.fontWeight = "bold"; //thx René Roth comments
}
```

Comment: or just set font-weight to bold

Answer (score 1):

```
cell1.innerHTML = "<p onclick=\"bold(this)\">words</p>;
```

**Script:**

```
function bold(obj) {
 obj..style.fontWeight="bold";
}
```